# Plotting/finding perimeter of data on a scatter plot

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, scatter-plot, area

Regarding the included graph (It's been ListLinePlotted to show the data sets more clearly),

1: How would I find and or plot the perimeter of each data set; ideally in List form, so it will scale when I plot it using LisLogPlot alongside the original data. (Similar to FindCurvePath, but for a non-round shape)

2: How would I fill the entire area encompassed by the data set on the ListPlot. i.e. the resulting graph would have four block color areas in the shape of each region.

Essentially I'm just trying plot graphs which clearly show the different regions. If there are better ways then I'd be open to suggestions!

P.S. the regions will never intersect for this particular plot.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for ConvexHull[]? Overlay a Graphics with hulls as polygons?

Comment: his regions are definately not convex. Is that data calculated on a regular grid? that would help to know.